# Efficiency of List creation from array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, list, type-conversion

I need to create a list starting from an array already created immediately before and will only be converted to the list. So I could harness the array to the list without making a copy, but [the constructor makes a copy](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs,d2ac2c19c9cf1d44). I can even understand the motivation for this. However there are cases that I can guarantee that the array does not have and will have no reference to it other than where it was created from.

Is there any way to make this construction more efficient and use the array internally in the list? I know there are implications if I misuse it.

The most obvious example for this is to get the result of a `string.Split()`. If you need a list your only obvious way out would be to do this conversion. For now I'm not considering writing a method to split directly into a list.

Comment: Try : string.Split().ToList() so you do not create the array.

Comment: @jdweng It creates an array and converts to a List.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't create a variable.  So later in your code you don't have to create the list as a 2nd variable.

Comment: I think you cannot avoid the copy of an array. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54298050/fastest-way-from-iterator-to-list-in-c-sharp/54298591#54298591.

Comment: @jdweng my problem is not the variable, is the object.

Comment: @Johnny is I know that. But maybe it is a less known alternative.

Comment: @Maniero I am also interested in that if any :)

Comment: When you add an object to a list is does not make a copy.  It uses a link to the original object.

Comment: @Maniero Generally you could retrieve the internal _items array and use memcpy to copy the array and just update _size field but it is a bit dirty hack...I have managed to do something like that...

Comment: Most likely this is done for security reasons. Of course, you understand where such code may lead, but some people do not understand this.

Comment: @jdweng I get an array, I'm not saying about add elements. And it's more complicated that you say. Anyway it's not my problem here.

Comment: @Johnny I need convert an array to a List not get the underlaying array from List, and I want avoid copy, your solution does copy.

Comment: @Vasek Not exactally for security but problably it is about protect programmer to shoot yourself having an external reference to underlying array in List.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to say

Comment: @Maniero then just set _items and _size using reflection?

Comment: @Johnny My question is more about an official way, but your suggestion could work, I will try.

Comment: @Maniero I understand, my suggestion is for sure not official, but it works, I will share the solution...

Comment: If you do not need to change the list later, look at [Array.AsReadOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.asreadonly?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_AsReadOnly__1___0___). If I understand everything correctly, there will be no copies

Comment: @Vasek thanks, but I need change it later.

Comment: Should that "change it later" operation impact the contents of the list as well? Or did you mean "change the LIST later"? In other words, please be specific and please explain *all* your criteria.

Comment: Having said that, is there any reason why you did not just create a list to begin with and fill that with data instead of the array?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen read the last paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no official way to do that but it is still possible using `System.Reflection`. By looking at the source code of the `List<T>`, **.NET Framework 4.7.2**, the two important properties are `_items` and `_size`. There is also `_version` but that one changes only when you modify `List<T>`. Modification are `Add`, `AddRange`, `Remove`, etc. but also `Reverse` and `Sort`. So let's assume this is the same operation as creating the list from `IEnumerable<T>` where `_version` stays zero.

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void SetUnderlyingArray<T>(this List<T> list, T[] array)
    {
        lock (list)
        {
            SetInternalArray(list, array);
            SetInternalArraySize(list, array.Length);
        }
    }

    private static void SetInternalArraySize<T>(this List<T> list, int size)
    {
        var prop = list.GetType().GetField(
            "_size", 
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        prop.SetValue(list, size);
    }

    private static void SetInternalArray<T>(this List<T> list, T[] array)
    {
        var prop = list.GetType().GetField(
            "_items",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        prop.SetValue(list, array);
    }
}
```

and then set the underlying array

```
int[] array = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 1000000).ToArray();
List<int> list = new List<int>();

list.SetUnderlyingArray(array);
```

---

**Note** This solution is highly dependent on the details of the implementation and might be wrong if something change in the `List<T>` internals but it gives insight on how it could be accomplished.

Comment: I will try. I don´t want this solution exactly because it is detail dependent. But probably this is the only option. If `_items` were `protected` it would be ease.

Comment: @Maniero Exactly. I stated that dependency I am aware of that and I do understand your concern...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specifically need a `List<T>` You could create a new class that implements `IList<T>` and doesn't make a copy.

Comment: This is an option if everything fails, I thought about that, it-s a radical way, but it's a valid one.

Comment: I'd say it's less radical than a reflection approach. There's no dependency on the implementation of `List<T>`

Comment: Yep, reflection is radical too